# If $f \in R[a,b]$ and $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ . . . show $\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{b}g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The full problem is

(a)

If a function $f : [a; b] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) = 0$ for all but finitely many points $x \in [a, b]$, prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f=0$

(b)

If $f \in R[a,b]$ and if $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is obtained by altering finitely many points, show that $g \in R[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{b}g$.

I have part (A), but I don't understand how to do part (B). Someone told me to try the difference $h=g-f$ and apply part (A) since then both $f$ and $h$ are integrable and $g=h+f$.

Comment: What they said is correct and basically the full proof. What more do you want?

Comment: $h=g-f\neq0$ for all but finitely many points in $[a,b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$
\left|\int_a^b f-\int_a^b g\right| \leq \int_a^b |f-g|
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a) The function is the sum of Dirac delta functions
       b) $g$ is the sum of $f$ + Dirac delta functions